# DB2 Creating temporary table as

Tags: triggers, db2

I cannot create temporary table in my trigger, whats wrong here?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BOOKSTORE
    NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON BOOKSTORE
     REFERENCING NEW AS NEWBOOKSTORE
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
         
        BEGIN
        DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_EMP (INTEGER) AS
        (SELECT 1 
        FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
        WITH DATA ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
        END;
WHEN (NEWBOOKSTORE.NAME = '')
SIGNAL SQLSTATE 123 ('Not allowed name')
```

ERROR:

```
{0:0} An unexpected token "SELECT" was found following "SESSION.TEMP_EMP AS
".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Comment: The SELECT must be between brackets. [see](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-declare-global-temporary-table)

Comment: The error still exists.

Comment: What is your Db2-server PLATFORM *z/os mainframe,  i -series (as400),  linux/unix/windows/cloud   ?    There are restrictions on exactly which SQL statements are allowed in a trigger body, but you can use CALL to a routine to workaround in some cases.  Also, your question should be edited to __show your code__  of the trigger, and whether your database is partitioned or not.

Comment: Just works with defined column definition. But got error with the `When` clause after it, without `When` it is working
`{0:0} An unexpected token "END" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "MMIT PRESERVE ROWS".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11`

Comment: Can you explain the logic you are trying to implement? The WHEN clause is usually declared directly after `FOR EACH ROW`. What is the purpose of the temporary table?

Comment: I solved it with if.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.